# How can I get maven to continue module builds after reaching surefire forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds threshhold

Tags: maven, timeout, maven-surefire-plugin

In a multi module mvn 3.0 build, I set forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds to one hour.  If tests in module A hang, I hit surefire threshold which will fails the build and skips remaining modules.   We use a junit timeouts which should kill hung tests prior to this but some scenarios encounter this problem.  I'd like to keep my builds running while I investigate enhancements to our junit runner.

Current Command Line:  `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore`

- How I can change the surefire timeout behavior to move to next module and continue the build?
- Does anyone have tips for testing one's junit framework?

I was going to review the surefire project's integration tests for ideas for both items.  I plan to have a junitsystest module which activated by a specific profile so I can test various problematic situations outside of my builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mastering The Maven Command Line – Managing failures](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/06/07/mastering-the-maven-command-line-%E2%80%93-managing-failures/) **--fail-at-end** or **--fail-never** will provide the desired results.  Surefire timeout continues to be reported but doesn't halt the build.

Not recommending in the long run as it lengthens bad build times

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore --fail-never`